# Email action in flow send Visualforce Email template Issue

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow

I have a record trigger flow that should send an email when a campaign is created. The email template is a Visual force. I keep on getting this error when trying it.

Error element Blast_Email_Alert (FlowActionCall).

We were unable to process the email template. Error Message: core.email.template.TemplateRenderingException: Unable to retrieve object

In my email action I am passing the record.id as variable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Visualforce email template used in your flow's email action cannot access the necessary data. The record.Id you're passing might not provide the right context for your Visualforce email template to function correctly. It's possible that the template expects a Campaign object while you might be passing the Id only.